# Using an Angular function to dynamically add a number of images based on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm pulling data from a Google Spreadsheet and the input is something like "4-asdf".

I use Javascript to split this by the dash like so

```
var arr = input.split('-');
var stars = arr[0];
```

I want to parse the stars element so that I add that number of stars for a rating. This code lies within a $scope function called parseRating.

On the frontend, I have something this

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places">
  {{ parseRating(place.input) }}
</div>
```

Is there any way I can return images with Angular? I know I can return strings with that function. Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to repeat the same element (a star image) based on the rating.

so I would do it like this

```
<div ng-repeat="star in parseRating(place.input) track by $index">
    <img src="star.gif" >
<div>
```

in the controller I would do something like:

```
$scope.parseRating = function(input) {
    var arr = input.split('-');
    var stars = arr[0];
    return new Array(stars * 1);   
};
```

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXg4Y9bGIx87AWzdrIiF)

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. How about if I wanted to do half stars? So I have another img path for a half star but is there a way to insert logic in Angular to check for half star ratings?

Comment: @ChangLiu yes, I'll post another answer soon, question is - what is the input for a half star? "0.5-asdf"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with half stars, you can do it like this:

```
$scope.parseRating = function(input) {
    var starSrc = 'http://aslservices.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/star.png';
    var halfStarSrc = 'http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/12/123796/4243160-0250959220-half-.jpg';
    var arr = input.split('-');
    var stars = arr[0];
    var srcs = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < stars[0] *1; i++){
      srcs.push(starSrc);
    }
    if(stars.length > 1) srcs.push(halfStarSrc);
    return srcs;
};
```

and then in your html code, you do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="star in parseRating('2.5-kl') track by $index">
      <img src="{{star}}">
    </div>
```

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXg4Y9bGIx87AWzdrIiF?p=preview)